# Spring boot application giving exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/bind/Bindable "

Tags: spring-boot, noclassdeffounderror, amazon-ami

[image]

We have one spring-boot application running Apache Tomcat 8.5.42 and AWS AMI having AMazon Correto JDK java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto.x86_64 (JVM Version:1.8.0_222-b10).
Very recently we have upgraded our apps AMI and it has started giving error as

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.OAuth2AutoConfiguration]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/bind/Bindable

It was not giving any error till the time. Just after AMI upgarde it started giving error.

What would be reason for this and whats ideal solution?

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.okta.jwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>okta-jwt-verifier</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

depandancies are updated

Comment: Please add your dependencies

Comment: looks like some problem with dependencies

Comment: dependencies are added.

Comment: See https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/13/overriding-dependency-versions-with-spring-boot. Stop definng a version for the oauth2 autoconfigure.